# Laravel связь один к одному

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Добрый день,

**Не могу правильно установить связь один-к-одному в `Laravel 4`**

Есть таблица `Users` и таблица `Country`
В таблице `Users` есть поле `country_id`, а таблица `Country` имеет поле `id`
В моделе `User` прописываю метод

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Country', 'id', 'country_id');
}
```

но выборка производится не по полю `users.country_id` а по `users.id`
прошу помочь, видимо я чего-то не до понимаю

Comment: Попробуйте просто return $this->hasOne('Country');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы перепутали внешний и внутренний ключи, должно быть наоборот:

```
return $this->hasOne('Country', 'country_id', 'id');
```